# Graphic card for parallel programming vs traditional methods

Tags: parallelism

With a simple search in amazon one can see that the modern approach for parallel programming is to use your graphic card. However I am still a little bit skeptical about it. My last computer has an 8 core CPU which I need is enough for basic all my parallel needs, if I need more I will probably use MPI through a network using my old machines. All in all, Why and/or when should I use CUDA or another method which uses my graphic card instead of traditional methods like pthreads, java threads, boost threads or the new C++ 11 threads? What about using processes?

Comment: "640K ought to be enough for anybody!"...

Comment: 8 CPUs? What hardware are you sporting? That's far from common.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe because even a mid-range Graphics card is a couple of orders of magnitude faster than an 8 core CPU at **the tasks it is very good at**, which is **highly parallel algorithms**?

8 Core CPU == 8 threads **minus** any OS threads that are available for your Application ( and that is only if you actually have 8 `REAL` cores, Hyper Threading doesn't count! )

512 Stream GPU = 512 Streams for your application to use.

Also the memory bandwidth on modern graphics cards are at least twice as wide and a few orders of magnitude faster than even the fastest chipset available for a general purpose CPU.

The question is confusing multi-threading with parallel concurrency which are not always used together.

GPUs aren't multi-threaded in the same way a general purpose CPU is.

`Stream != Thread`

That is they don't execute multiple instructions per stream, but streams can share data that they work on, which general purpose CPUs can't do well, at least not without compromising in space over time issues. It really is comparing Apples and Oranges.

Comment: With HT enabled you can have 16 threads ;)

Comment: those aren't real threads they are pretend threads on an Intel box, and you don't get 1:1 performance with Hyper Threading and in some cases you get less performance with all the context switching and cache misses that Hyper Threading causes.

Comment: In all fairness, the same applies to streams. A stream processor can only run one instruction at a time, so unless all streams are trying to execute the same instruction some streams will be idle, and therefore you usually don't get 1:1 performance on GPU's either.

Comment: An which ones are these tasks? When should I say: hey, I rather use my GPU than my processor?

Comment: @MSalters notice my qualifier of "...the tasks it is very good at..." And yes you do get 1:1 performance on appropriate tasks. A 512 stream GPU encoding video will be 2X as faster as a 256 stream GPU running the same code on the same input.

Comment: @Sambatyon Use your GPU when you need a couple mil floating point operations per second.  GPU does it all the time, albeit for a different purpose.

Comment: hyperthreading doesn't do context switching among threads; it keeps both contexts loaded in the CPU.  that's why they're "hardware threads".  they're far from being as efficient as separate cores; but with modern schedulers (like on every OS available) you'd be very hard pressed to find any parallelizable workload that doesn't benefit from HT.

Comment: hyper threading does context switch and does cause cache misses because it has to reload registers when threads move on and off threads, it is particular heinous at causing performance problems on Windows in particular. The GWT compiler suffers drastically on hyper threaded cpus, I have to only run the exact number of real cores and it runs FASTER than running on the hyper threaded cores on my i3. It isn't hard at all to find examples where hyper threading is crap, this is just one example of many I have had with hyper threading on intel processors being worse than not using it.

Answer (score 8):

A multi-core CPU is very good at MIMD work (Multiple Instructions Multiple Data). A GPU excels at SIMD work (Single Instruction Multiple Data). That means that if all your threads are running the same function, only on different data, then using a GPU is probably a good choice. A classic SIMD example is image processing, when all threads run the same algorithm on different parts of the image.

Comment: You mean a GPU is good at SIMD?